Overlay problem when importing a CSV file into QGIS
I'm having a problem with certain entities being superimposed when importing a delimited text file in .csv format into QGIS.
It seems that some entities lose their coordinates and copy the coordinates of another entity. Visually, the original data is not visible in the Canva, as it is superimposed on another entity. When we apply a click selection, we see that several entities are selected, whereas we only see one.
We have contacted the data supplier, who tells us that there is no problem with the data used, and that we need to choose the right delimiter when setting up the import. We did choose the appropriate delimiter, but the problem persists.

You can download an extract of the data at the following link:
https://doi.org/10.15468/dl.q9jj2u (2019)
https://doi.org/10.15468/dl.ea42gx (2022)

Can you share a subset of your data in order to be able to reproduce this? The dataset could have duplicate coordinates, you probably have issues choosing the correct separator. Hard to tell with the information provided.

Sharing screenshots and a sample of data would help to see what you see.

Thanks for your replies, I've made some changes to the post where you'll find an image. I can't open the .csv file because it's too large, but it's impossible for two entities to have the same coordinates since these are wildlife observations and each observation has its own coordinates. For the record, these are data collected on the GBIF API.

I was able to open the csv both with Notepad++ and Excell. The dataset has entities with same coordinates

You could use the "Point Displacement" renderer to visualize the superposed point

It would appear that the data has quality problems: in terms of completeness, topological consistency and positional accuracy. In fact, observers probably lack rigor when filling in their observations. This is a major source of error.
For other entities, the superposition is unexplained, as data observed by different observers and at different observation dates are superimposed. It's these problems that we can't correct because we can't find their origin.

The "Point Displacement" solution allows us to correct the problem, but does not allow us to fix it at its origin. It's still a solution!

The last decimal in lat/lon values means about 10 cm on the ground. It feels normal that several plant species grows on the same 10 by 10 cm square.

In this case, the image in the post shows a single observer and therefore a lack of rigor in the measurements. For other observations, the problem is encountered when, for example, two different bird species are observed on the same coordinate point by two different authors and on completely different dates.
